# Using DataTable.update() does not add entries to my SQL Server database in one method but does in another

Tags: c#, sql-server, datatable

I have a method (`AddRowToSQLTable()`) that is passed a row, it then creates a row array containing that row and then passes it to `DataTable.update()`.

This works fine. The SQL Server is updated and the next time I run (debug) the program the new data is present.

Another method (`AddStock()`) uses a similar structure but does not work.

The difference being that I am passing a data table in `Update()` not a `Row[]` however no exception is thrown just nothing is updated/added on the server.

Can someone please explain what exactly is going on and why these differ? I would like to know this even if the solution is to use a different structure to achieve what I want so I know for the future and have a better understanding.

To Note:

I have tested to ensure the `DataTable` being passed contains records. The `DataTable` is of the same format as the target SQL Server table.

I have also tried `SqlBulkCopy` and encounter the same problem.

Many thanks!

```
private DataTable StockAdditions;

public void PrepareStockQuantitiesForAdding()
{
        if (StockAdditions != null)
        {
            StockAdditions.Clear();
        }

        StockAdditions = StockQuantitiesTable.Clone();
        int Count = 0;

        DataRow RowToAdd = StockQuantitiesTable.NewRow();
        DataView AreaIDs = new DataView(AreaTable);
        DataView Conditions = new DataView(ConditionsTable);

        int AreaID;
        string ConditionCode;

        foreach (DataRow Row in SessionSKUScanned.Rows)
        {
            if (Row["Serial Number"].ToString() == "")
            {
                Conditions.RowFilter = "([Name] = '" + Row["Condition"] + "')";
                ConditionCode = Conditions[0][2].ToString();

                AreaIDs.RowFilter = "([StorageAreaName] = '" + Row["Area"] + "')";
                AreaID = Convert.ToInt32(AreaIDs[0][0]);

                DataView StockQuantities = new DataView(StockQuantitiesTable);
                StockQuantities.RowFilter = "([QuantityID] = '" + AreaID + "-" + Row["SKU"] + "-" + ConditionCode + "')";

                if (StockQuantities.Count > 0)
                {
                    StockQuantities[0][3] = Convert.ToInt32(StockQuantities[0][3]) + 1;

                    RowToAdd["QuantityID"] = AreaID + "-" + Row["SKU"] + "-" + ConditionCode;
                    RowToAdd["SKU"] = Row["SKU"];
                    RowToAdd["AreaID"] = AreaID;
                    RowToAdd["Quantity"] = StockQuantities[0][3] = Convert.ToInt32(StockQuantities[0][3]) + 1;
                    RowToAdd["Condition"] = Row["Condition"];
                }
                else
                {
                    RowToAdd["QuantityID"] = AreaID + "-" + Row["SKU"] + "-" + ConditionCode;
                    RowToAdd["SKU"] = Row["SKU"];
                    RowToAdd["AreaID"] = AreaID;
                    RowToAdd["Quantity"] = 1;
                    RowToAdd["Condition"] = Row["Condition"];
                }

                Count++;
            }
            else
            {
                RowToAdd["QuantityID"] = Row["Serial Number"];
                RowToAdd["SKU"] = Row["SKU"];
                AreaIDs.RowFilter = "([StorageAreaName] = '" + Row["Area"] + "')";
                RowToAdd["AreaID"] = Convert.ToInt32(AreaIDs[0][0]);
                RowToAdd["Quantity"] = 1;
                RowToAdd["Condition"] = Row["Condition"];

                Count++;
            }

            StockQuantitiesTable.ImportRow(RowToAdd);
            MessageBox.Show(RowToAdd[0].ToString());
            StockAdditions.ImportRow(RowToAdd);
        }
    }

    private void AddRowToSQLTable(DataRow Row, string SQLTableName)
    {
        DataRow[] Rows = new DataRow[1];
        Rows[0] = Row;

        SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["eCommStock.Properties.Settings.Demo_SiteConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

        SQLConn.Open();

        SqlDataAdapter daUpdateTable = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From " + SQLTableName, SQLConn);

        SqlCommandBuilder SQLcmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(daUpdateTable);

        daUpdateTable.Update(Rows);

        SQLConn.Close();
}

public void AddStock()
{
    SqlConnection SQLConn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["eCommStock.Properties.Settings.Demo_SiteConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

    SQLConn.Open();

    SqlDataAdapter daUpdateTable = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From StockQuantities", SQLConn);

    SqlCommandBuilder SQLcmdBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(daUpdateTable);

    daUpdateTable.Update(StockAdditions);

    SQLConn.Close();
}
```

Comment: where does StockAdditions come from? StockAdditions.GetChanges() returns rows? If it doens't adapter.Update() does nothing.

Comment: It's a datatable within the class that contains software side records that need to be sent to the SQLServer for update or insertion. I definitely feel like i could be using the wrong approach but don't really understand why it works in one method and not the other. SQLBulkCopy seems like a better fit maybe?

Comment: Does it contain changes? Have you called AcceptChanges somewhere?

Comment: Do i need to call AcceptChanges on StockAdditions? If so why? As i can reference the DataRows within it and get values?

Comment: I think you receive down votes because your question cannot be answered. The culprit code is somewhere else, but you did not show it.

Comment: If you call AcceptChanges and then adapter.Update no insert, update, deletes will go to database. That is the reason why I asked, because that might be the cause

Comment: I have no AcceptChanges calls anywhere (wasn't necessary in the first method) . The problem i have is the class is quite large so knowing what is relevant is difficult. I am very new to using C# to manipulate SQL servers so i'm at a stage where i'm not even sure what i don't know as such, ensuring the question is relevant is a struggle!

Comment: Could it be in any way related to the rows in stock additions being imported using the ImportRow method?

Comment: Show us the code that deal with StockAdditions from the row addition to adapter.Update. How are you adding rows to StockAdditions?

Comment: Have changed .update to .fill and had the same result. I don't understand how this can be behaving like this and not throwing an exception.

Comment: Why fill should raise an exception? It queries the database and it fills the datatable with the rows returned from the database.

Comment: So it get the rows from StockAdditons and adds/updates them on the server. There are confirmed rows in stock additions yet no data is modified on the server. This confuses me because no exceptions are thrown either. so why is that data not being added to the table on the server?

Comment: I'm fairly certain i should be using SQLBulkCopy upon looking into this again. So have returned to using it ...however i am still not getting any result on the server.

Comment: SO the problem is that:" StockAdditions.ImportRow(RowToAdd);" isn't actually adding andything to StockAdditions. Why is this?

Comment: RowToAdd.RowState is Detached, importing a Detached Row results in a Detached row, the row needs to be in Added state to be inserted into the database.

Comment: So what do you suggest i do?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because RowToAdd.RowState is Detached. I don't like it, but the following is a quick and dirty solution, before importing the row to StockAdditions, make sure the row is in Added state, later you can "detach" the row again.

```
StockQuantitiesTable.Rows.Add(RowToAdd);
StockAdditions.ImportRow(RowToAdd);
StockQuantitiesTable.Rows.Remove(RowToAdd);
```